# Bitwise unpacking using signed data

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I've been trying for a while pack & unpack some chars into an integer. Although there are some topics related to this question, my problem is related with the signed shift. I don't get the 'trick' to unpack a signed value, i.e.:

```
char c1 = -119;
char c2 = 26;

// pack
int packed = (unsigned char)c1 | (c2 << 8);
// unpack
c1 = packed >> 0;
c2 = packed >> 8;

// printf(c1, c2) -> Unpacked data: -119 | 26
```

That works as expected but when i try to pack more data, i.e:

```
char c0 = -42;
char c1 = -119;
char c2 = 26;

// pack
int packed = (unsigned char)c0 | (unsigned char)(c1 << 8) | (c2 << 16);
// unpack
c0 = packed >> 0;
c1 = packed >> 8;
c2 = packed >> 16;

// printf -> Unpacked data: -42 | 0 | 26
```

**c1** value is missed. I guess It's related to something with *the sign bit is shifted into the high-order position*.

How could i get back *c1* value?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are casting `c1` to `unsigned char` *after* shifting it out of the range of that type, so the result of the cast is zero. You should do the cast before shifting:

```
int packed = (unsigned char)c0 | ((unsigned char)c1 << 8) | (c2 << 16);
```

Comment: Good explanation :) There is no place for doubts. Thanks you!

Answer (score 2):

```
(unsigned char)(c1 << 8)
```

This will

- shift the wrong (sign-extended) value
- trim the result to 8 bits (yielding 0)

You don't want any of that so you should use `((unsigned char)c1 << 8)`.

Comment: Untrue.  Casting signed to unsigned is never undefined behavior, no matter how wide or narrow the types are.  (In contrast to casting unsigned to signed.). The code is still wrong, but it is not UB.

Answer (score 0):

Some `int`s are 16bits. For this code to be portable use `int32_t`. The correct way to accomplish this (if slightly paranoid) is:

```
int32_t packed = ((uint8_t)c0) | (((uint8_t)c1)<<8) | (((uint8_t)c2) << 16);
```

I also tend to list these in reverse order, so it is more natural which characters become the most and least significant bytes.